# JQuery get 'id' attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have the following code that generates a table and applies a click function to each td within the table. It also applies an incremental id starting with 1. When the user clicks on a td element I'm trying to retrieve the id of the `<td>` they clicked on. However the value of selector is [object Window]. I'm sure it is something simple but I none of the similar questions on here have helped, and I'm not seeing it.

```
$("#CMGame").click(function() {
    $("#TTTContent").hide();
    $("#CMContent").show();

    var board = $("#CMBoard");
    var htmlString = "";
    var count = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        htmlString += "<tr>";
        for (var i2 = 0; i2 < 20; i2++) {
            count++;
            htmlString += "<td id='" + toString(count) + "'></td>";
        }
        htmlString += "</tr>";
    }

    board.html(htmlString);

    $("#CMBoard td").click(function() {
        var piece = $(this);
        var selector = piece.attr('id');
        alert(selector);
        /*
        if (CMBArray[selector] != 1 OR CMBArray[selector] != 2) {
            CMBArray[selector] = 1;
            piece.addClass('selected');
        }
        */


    });

});
```

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: The `td` id you create can't be just a number. it has to start with a letter.

Comment: @LGSon I added a C in front. Now selector is C[object Window] Maybe there is an issue with toString(count) ?

Comment: can you provide this _toString_? your code seems work if avoid it http://jsfiddle.net/as5v3xxu/

Comment: Well yes, you can remove that or change it to `count.toString()`, which is the correct way.

Comment: @Grundy Thanks! that did it. Would you mind adding that as an answer so that I can check it. Also, toString() is a built in conversion, I did not create that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 errors in your code, the `td` id you create can't be just a number, it has to start with a letter and then you can either remove `toString(count)` and use only `count` or change it to `count.toString()`, which is the correct way.

Here is the specs. for a DOM `id`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

And here for `toString()`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString

Comment: _toString_ not needed,

Comment: @LGSon Thanks again, though just for testing I tried it with only the number for the id and that still worked. It did not require a letter.

Comment: An id should start with a letter though it doesn't mean it will not work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Answer (score 1):

The toString is wrong in the code. Change

```
toString(count)
```

to

```
count.toLocaleString()
```

Answer (score 1):

`toString(count)` is effectively like saying `this.toString()` which, in your case basically means `window.toString()`, which results in `[object Window]`.

Instead, use `count.toString()`.

Here's a quick test:

```js
var count = 0;

console.log('second toString: ' + toString(count) );

console.log('second toString: ' + count.toString );
```

Bear in mind that, whenever you concatonate strings in Javascript, the `toString` method is called on all objects by default. For example, these two expressions yield the same output:

```js
var number = 5;

console.log( 'The number is ' + number.toString() );
console.log( 'The number is ' + number );
```

Comment: _toString(count) is effectively like saying this.toString()_ you wrong here

Comment: @Grundy I don't see how. Calling `toString` in the global namespace basically calls the Window Object's `toString` method. Can you elaborate on the term *wrong*?

Comment: i mean `toString` not like `this.toString` it indeed `window.toString`

Answer (score 0):

The toString method you are calling is actually window.toString.
By not specifying a parent object for toString, you are invoking the method on the global window object. That is why you see "[object Window]", it is returning a string representation of the invoking object.

You don't need the toString at all. Javascript cast numberics to a string when you add it to a string.

Answer (score -1):

`this.id` will return the id of the a jQuery element.   E.g.:

```
$("td").click(function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: if fiddle you change code, not only click handler: [really fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4dmspt3/1/)

Comment: Gosh, there are two problems in his code, but his question asked about one.  the other problem has already been addressed above.

Comment: Could you add some text in your answer explaining why this is the answer to the question? I would also suggest adding the fiddle reference in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is in the event $("#CMGame").click(function()
when try to convert to string with toString(count) javascript and jquery don't understand that they do understand count.toString() here is the source [javaScript toString function](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/toString).

Suggestion about some code you have:

- first this one var board = $("#CMBoard"); you pass the html element to a  javascript variable for you can do this board.html(htmlString); i think you do that so your function can be more faster than using other method to manipulate the DOM but in this case it look that we are not looking for best performances so other option is keep it simple with this $("#CMBoard").append(htmlString)
- The id you set to each  element is a number that is not a good practice at all and also there is a suggestion for compatibility for HTML5 to HTML4 look;
  Note: Using characters except ASCII letters and digits, '_', '-' and '.' may cause compatibility problems, as they weren't allowed in HTML 4. Though this restriction has been lifted in HTML 5, an ID should start with a letter for compatibility. you can find this in [global attribute id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) so is better to set a real id name you can do something like this in your code `htmlString += "<td id='item_" + count.toString() + "'></td>";`
  so the id will come out like id="item_1"

Comment: why you think _The td element do not support id attribute_? can you provide link to specification?

Comment: @Grundy it was my mistake id is a global attribute type here the link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id